# Automatically run macro at 4 points in the day

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro 4 times in a day. 10:10 am, 12:25 pm, 15:25 PM and 18:15 PM.

This excel file is opened in the morning and is open all day. The following day the file is re-saved under a new date name and is open all day.

I think I got it working to automatically update once, but it doesn't seem to work for the rest. I used what I found online to make it automatically run once at 10:10 am.

This part is in "ThisWorkbook" under "Workbook" and "Open"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:10:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
End Sub
```

Then the next part is in the module that the macro is saved in. The macro just refreshes a data connection.

```
Sub UpdateManifestpending()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:10:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
'
' UpdateManifestpending Macro
'

'
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ManifestPendingUpdates").Refresh
End Sub
```

I would like to have this run, not only just that one time at 10:10, but at the other times of the day listed above. I tried this to have it run 4 times a day but it doesn't seem to work.

In "thisworkbook"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:10:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:15:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:25:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:25:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
End Sub'
```

And under the ModuleID for the macro

```
`Sub UpdateManifestpending()

Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:10:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:15:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:25:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:25:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"

'
' UpdateManifestpending Macro
'

'
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ManifestPendingUpdates").Refresh
End Sub

`
```

I might be misunderstanding how this activate.ontime works
Anyhelp is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

1. **Code 1:** A `WorkBook_Open` which calls your scheduler macro
2. **Code 2:** Your scheduler macro which calls the code to be ran at given times
3. **Code 3:** your code to be ran at given times
4. **Home Stretch:** Validate <kbd>Security Settings</kbd> to allow this type series of steps to be executed

---

### Code 1

Under the code space for `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Scheduler
End Sub
```

---

### Code 2

Under a `Module` code space you will have 2 sets of code.

```
Sub Scheduler()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:10:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("12:15:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:25:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:25:00"), "UpdateManifestpending"
End Sub
```

### Code 3

```
Sub UpdateManifestpending()
    'Code here
End Sub
```

---

### Home Stretch

You will need to allow programmatic access to the VB project

Navigate to `Trust Center > Macro Settings` and select `Trust access to the VBA project object module`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a public module, put this dynamic scheduling code.

```
sub runWhen()

    Select Case Time
        Case Is < TimeSerial(10, 10, 0)
            Application.OnTime TimeSerial(10, 10, 0), "UpdateManifestpending"
        Case Is < TimeSerial(12, 25, 0)
            Application.OnTime TimeSerial(12, 25, 0), "UpdateManifestpending"
        Case Is < TimeSerial(15, 25, 0)
            Application.OnTime TimeSerial(15, 25, 0), "UpdateManifestpending"
        Case Is < TimeSerial(18, 15, 0)
            Application.OnTime TimeSerial(18, 15, 0), "UpdateManifestpending"
    End Select

end sub
```

In ThisWorkbook,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    runWhen
End Sub
```

Add the scheduling to UpdateManifestpending just before End Sub.

```
sub UpdateManifestpending()

   'lots of code here

    runWhen
End Sub
```

Comment: OP back, I tried the first suggestion that urdearboy mentioned at that is working flawlessly! thank you